# Surgemail DNS lookup failure

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp

Just curious if anyone has any experience with Surgemail. I've set it up a couple times and never had an issue but my latest install keeps leaving outgoing messages in the queue with the error "DNS Lookup Failed". I double checked that the local DNS server is running and even tried switching the IPs to my ISP's DNS servers but still no go.

```
[DNS]                Ok(avge)    Bad(avge)
  76.227.63.137:      0(0.0s)      5(31.0s)
  76.227.63.254:      0(0.0s)      1(0.0s)
```

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up and switched to HMailServer. It's been working smoothly ever since. :P

Answer (score 0):

Are any messages getting through?  Maybe an error looking up MX records for the recipient's domain?

Comment: No none. And I'm sending test emails to well known domains like yahoo.com and gmail.com.